# Is there public documentation for a SAP Marketing Cloud (CRM) API?

Tags: sap-crm, sap-marketing-cloud

I'm trying to find API documentation for the SAP Marketing Cloud API, but all I've found is this:

https://api.sap.com/api/API_MKT_CONTACT_SRV_0004/resource

But this only seems to provide a way to list/search for contacts, with no endpoints for CRUD operations.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the right place,
if there are not all CRUD functions available, then this is not to be supported by the public API.

For the overview you can use this link:
https://api.sap.com/package/SAPS4HANAMarketingCloud/odata

BR